# Property of quasipositive matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis

I saw this theorem stated in a paper without proof and I have difficulty proving it.

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with non-negative off-diagonal entries, let $s(A)$ be the real eigenvalue such that $s(A)> Re(\lambda(A))$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$. From properties of $Z$-matrices, we know such an eigenvalue exists.

Let $M$ and $L$ are two matrices with non-negative off-diagonal entries and $M<L$ (implying $m_{ij}<l_{ij}$ for all $i,j$) , how do we prove $s(M)<s(L)$?

Comment: For ordinary nonnegative matrices, the Perron root is monotonic in the entries of the matrix, so that if $M$ and $L \ge 0$, then if $M < L \implies \rho(M) < \rho(L)$. The same kind of argument probably extends to your problem also.

Comment: @Suvrit's comment hits the spot. It suffices to add a large multiple of the identity to both matrices to make them nonnegative, and then Perron's result applies.